# Need something akin to DISTINCT ON (a) AND DISTINCT ON (b) where normal DISTINCT clause isn't working

Tags: postgresql, distinct

Just as a preface, I've tried using `SELECT DISTINCT ON(a, b)` and `SELECT DISTICNT ON (a) ... UNION SELECT DISTINCT ON (b)` but neither worked, so I'm reaching out for a possible solution.

I have two tables, player and card (a card represents something like a hitman's contract, with a reference to the 'killer' and the 'victim' which both reference the player table).

When a killer successfully kills a victim, the victim's state is set to 'dead' and their card is freed (by setting the card's killer_id to NULL), entering a kind of "free card pool". The killer is then set to 'idle' (as in waiting for a new card to be assigned to them), and their now completed card is set to completed.

What I'm trying to do is assign idle players cards from the freed card pool, with the additionaly caveat that a player can never receive themselves as a target, i.e. JOINing `card.victim_id ON player.id` is not allowed. So performing:

```
SELECT c.id AS card_id, p.id AS player_id 
FROM card c
FULL OUTER JOIN player p ON true
WHERE p.state = 'idle'
  AND c.killer_id IS NULL
  AND c.victim_id != p.id;
```

returns all possible combinations of cards and players. What I need though is for every card and every player to be combined uniquely, which is to say that every card is assigned to a player and every player is assigned a card, where no card_id or player_id has appeared in a previous row. [I've created a DB fiddle here to illustrate my point](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ow6jYm5ZSKNsgH95F95WTC/2).

So given the above query, say I get the following dataset:

```
|   card_id   |   player_id   |
|-------------|---------------|
|      2      |       1       |
|      4      |       1       |
|      2      |       3       |
|      4      |       3       |
```

I want to pare it down into one of the following:

```
|   card_id   |   player_id   |      |   card_id   |   player_id   |
|-------------|---------------|  OR  |-------------|---------------|
|      2      |       1       |      |      2      |       3       |
|      4      |       3       |      |      4      |       1       |
```

where there are no duplicate values for either column, but the actual combo of card_id and player_id itself doesn't matter.

As stated before, I tried using both `SELECT DISTINCT ON(card_id, player_id)` and `SELECT DISTICNT ON (card_id) ... UNION SELECT DISTINCT ON (player_id)` but neither worked.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So how do you decide whether card_id 2 should have player_id 1 or 3?

Comment: @eurotrash I don't, that's part of what I'm trying to figure out. Ultimately it doesn't matter which combination of card_id and player_id there is, as long as the card_id and player_id haven't appeared in any other rows.

Comment: Does this work for you then? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ow6jYm5ZSKNsgH95F95WTC/3

Comment: @eurotrash unfortunately not - by joining card.victim_id on player.id, I'm essentially saying that a player can receive themselves as a kill target, which shouldn't be possible. I'll add that detail to my question.